# anyone got an error i get while installing teepluss/theme in laravel

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

I wanted to install **`teepluss/theme`** so I added it to my `composer.json`

[image]

but now I get this error:

> **[Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\FatalThrowableError]
>
>     Class 'SuperClosure\Serializer' not found**

[image]

---

I was capable to solve the first error by adding         >**`"jeremeamia/superclosure": "^2.0"`**

but now when I add >**`Teepluss\Theme\ThemeServiceProvider::class`**, in app.php providers I get a new error :

> **> [ErrorException]                 Illegal offset type in unset**

[image]
[image]

---

here's what i got in the script in composer.json 
[image]

Comment: i added         "jeremeamia/superclosure": "^2.0" in my composer json but now i get another error :  [ErrorException]              
  Illegal offset type in unset

Comment: Can you provide the entries under `scripts` in `composer.json` file.

Comment: please show your change in config/app.php

Comment: https://kopy.io/yGqS7 my app when i remove the theme in both alias and providers the error goes away but i need :/

Comment: i updated my post . you can fin the entries under scripts

Comment: can you add the last exception appear in `storage/logs/laravel.log`, if you want clear this file then execute the command and take the error appears

Answer (score 1):

If you already run `composer update`, you can try run this script
`php artisan config:cache`
and
`php artisan cache:clear`.It can help you resolve that problem

Comment: when i type it i got this new error "   Illegal offset type in unset "